# Where were "the Sparrows" prior to their encampment in front of the Great Sept?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Do we know where exactly the Sparrows came from? On a wiki of ice and fire, [Faith of the Seven](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Faith_of_the_Seven) they note that there was an increase in *religious fervor*. Is this a change primarily among the people of King's Landing or migrants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sparrows came from the smallfolk, most of whom were displaced by the War of the Five Kings. From your link:

> Many pilgrims and refugees, often called "sparrows", took up the badges and arms of Poor Fellows to protect themselves and other homeless victims of the war.

A wiki of Ice and Fire also has an article on the [Sparrows](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sparrows) based on Brienne's interactions with holy men in AFFC:

> During the War of the Five Kings, septs were despoiled and men and women sworn to the Faith were killed, mutilated and injured. From this holy men and those they collected on the way marched on King's Landing bringing the bones of those Faith sworn men and women who had been slain to lay before the king and plead for protection. They took the name 'sparrow' because the sparrow is the most common bird and those that marched were the most common of those sworn to the Faith.